# Draw a rectangle with texture (VertexPositionTexture) in Xna 3d

Tags: xna

I am tryig to draw a rectangle with texture using VertexPositionTexture but I get an error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred
>   in Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.dll
>
> Additional information: XNA Framework Reach profile requires
>   TextureAddressMode to be Clamp when using texture sizes that are not
>   powers of two.

Thanks.

Comment: The error message is explicit.  Use a power-of-two-sized texture, set [sampler state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.samplerstate_members.aspx) mode to clamp, or change the graphics profile to hi-def.  Doing any one of those would solve your problem.

Comment: Well, the edit review staff disagrees with me that your code dump is unrelated to your problem, but you aren't doing anything wrong in your vertexes or your usage of them.  You just need to read what the error message says. Only one out of the three possible solutions involves inserting a single line of code (sampler state setting).

Comment: Solved my problem, just changed it to hi-def.Thank you!

Comment: Just be aware that Hi-def will not work on all computers (if I remember correctly).

Comment: @Colton very few modern computers can't handle the hi-def profile.  It applies more to the windows phone targetting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three options:

(1) Try adding this line:

```
GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0] = SamplerState.LinearClamp;
```

This may change the appearance of the texture.

(2)

Change the height and width of the texture such that height * width is a power of 2. (i.e. ((2^9) * (2^9)) = 512*512 = 2^18)

(3) Change the XNA profile from Reach to Hi-def.

```
Right-click your project in Solution Explorer
Choose Properties
Focus the XNA Game Studio tab, and make your selection
```

(http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/07/19/selecting-reach-vs-hidef.aspx)

Comment: Better include the 3rd option: since the OP used it.  :)